# Pandas rolling mean on time series

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I am trying to calculate a rolling average for windows of 10 minute each on timeseries data. I have the data frame in the following format:

```
               Date      Time  Reading
0        2016/08/01   0: 0: 0    7.297
1        2016/08/01   0: 0: 1    7.047
2        2016/08/01   0: 0: 2    6.826
3        2016/08/01   0: 0: 3    6.641
4        2016/08/01   0: 0: 4    6.694
5        2016/08/01   0: 0: 5    7.055
6        2016/08/01   0: 0: 6    7.676
7        2016/08/01   0: 0: 7    8.840
8        2016/08/01   0: 0: 8    9.150
9        2016/08/01   0: 0:10    8.790
10       2016/08/01   0: 0:11    8.840
11       2016/08/01   0: 0:12    8.650
12       2016/08/01   0: 0:13    8.280
13       2016/08/01   0: 0:14    7.834
14       2016/08/01   0: 0:15    7.897
15       2016/08/01   0: 0:16    7.828
16       2016/08/01   0: 0:17    7.964
17       2016/08/01   0: 0:18    8.270
18       2016/08/01   0: 0:19    8.310
19       2016/08/01   0: 0:20    8.200
20       2016/08/01   0: 0:21    8.380
21       2016/08/01   0: 0:22    8.460
22       2016/08/01   0: 0:23    8.400
23       2016/08/01   0: 0:24    8.060
24       2016/08/01   0: 0:25    8.040
25       2016/08/01   0: 0:26    8.690
26       2016/08/01   0: 0:27    9.090
27       2016/08/01   0: 0:29    8.750
28       2016/08/01   0: 0:30    8.670
```

As you can see, time resolution is 1 second. However, between sample 26 and 27 you can see that resolution is 2 seconds. I was using the rolling method, with a window = 600 and that's how I realized I didn't actually have 1 second resolution across all my data. I am new to pandas, so I went and look at the documentation, and found that in the newest Pandas version, one can use actual time as the window for the rolling mean, as:

```
df.resample('10min').mean()
```

This didn't work for me, because I think my timestamps are not on pandas timestamp format. How can I manipulate my data so that pandas recognizes my timestamps? or, is there any other suggestion on how to solve my problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure Pandas will parse correctly your timestamp (the usual representation for hours minutes seconds is `HH:MM:SS`) but you can try

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df.pop('Date') + ' ' + df.pop('Time').str.replace(' ',''))
# check that this variable contains the correct timestamp

df.set_index('timestamp', inplace = True)
```

Comment: Use `df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df.pop('Date') + ' ' + df.pop('Time').str.replace(' ',''))` if you want `pd.to_datetime()` to parse it correctly...

Comment: Thanks. That worked. I have a question though, why str.replace(' ','') ???